# Does "to be messed up"express a state the same way we say "be messy"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Several past participles can be used as adjectives to express state.

For example, the verb "**to break**",

We have the action "**I have broken the window**" and its current state "**the window is broken**".

We have the action "**I have boiled the egg**" and its current state "**the egg is boiled**".

So the adjectives "**broken**" and "**boiled**" are derived from the verbs "**to break**" and "**to boil**" respectively.

However, we don't have the adjective "**broky**" or "**boily**"

Ok, now, in the dictionary, we have this verb

> **[mess something <-> up](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mess-up?q=mess%20up)**: ​ to make something dirty or untidy
>
> *I don't want you messing up my nice clean kitchen.*

We have the action "**I have messed up the kitchen**" and so does "**to be messed up**" express a state as in "**the kitchen is messed up**"?

But at the same time, we also have the adjective "**messy**" and a noun "**mess**" in the dictionary

> **[messy](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/messy?q=messy)** (adj): dirty and/or untidy
>
> The house was always messy.

> **[mess](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mess_1?q=mess)** (noun): a dirty or untidy state
>
> The room was a mess.

And it seems native speakers say there is difference between "**the kitchen is messy**", "**the kitchen is a mess**" and "**the kitchen is messed up**"?

This is why English is so hard because you need experience, we can not rely on dictionaries.

Comment: I think we would say _The kitchen has been messed up_ or, more likely, _Someone has messed up the kitchen_. The adjectival form would be _messy_ or _in a mess_ rather than _messed up_.

Comment: @KateBunting, but why some past participles can be used as an adjective, but some can not as with "**be messed up**"?

Comment: In this particular case, the verb _to mess up_ is derived from the noun _mess_, so we use an adjective also derived from the noun rather than a back-formation from the verb. _To break_ and _to boil_ are 'proper' verbs for which it is valid to use the past participle as an adjective.